# how to create a button that moves a shape's x value up each time a button is clicked?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

How do I create a button that moves a shape's y value up by 10 each time a button is clicked? This is what I have so far, but it only pushes the y value up once. I have a QML file a cpp file, and a .pro file the code for all three things is below.

Main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/MyRectangle/MyRectangle.qml"));
    if (!view.errors().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    view.show();


    app.exec();


}
```

MyRectangle.qml file:

```
// This is the shape I want to move up the y axis 
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle333
    x: 461
    y: 187
    width: 731
    height: 1
    color:"#ef5350"
    z: 2
}

// This is the "button" I want the user to press, that would trigger the movement.
Rectangle {
   id: myRect
   width: 18
   height: 18
   color: "transparent"
   x: 232
   y: 250
   z:132

MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea5
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: myRect.state == 'clicked' ? myRect.state = "" : 
    myRect.state = 'clicked';
}

states: [
     State {
     name: "clicked"
// Rectangle333 is the id of the shape that I want to move up the y axis.
     PropertyChanges { target: rectangle333; y:1}

      }
       ]
        }
```

Comment: what is `rectangle333`?

Comment: It's the id of the rectangle I want to move.

Comment: provide a [mcve] :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `states` do not fit your use case.

You can simply decrease the `Rectangle`'s y by 10 in the `onClicked` handler.
It is as simple as:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Item
{
   Rectangle
   {
       id: rectangle333
       color:"#ef5350"
       y: 50
       width: parent.width
       height: 1
   }

   Button
   {
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       text: "Move line up"
       onClicked: rectangle333.y-=10
   }

}
```